# Difference between building solution form visual studio by "Build Solution" or by using command utility aspnet_compiler

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio

Is there any difference between building solution form visual studio by "Build Solution" or by using command utility `aspnet_compiler -v     /solution`

Anyone please give me explanation on this ?

Comment: First of all, solution may have many different projects. Aspnet will only compile ASP.NET website project. All other projects compiled by different compilers, like csc or vbc. So, if you click "build solution", you will build all projects in solution. But with aspnet_compiler you probably will end-up building only your website.

Comment: BTW, "-v /solution" - is wrong. Because "v" is for virtual path. So, here we not even talking about the solution but the live website.